# Problems with connection laptop to TV via HDMI

Tags: nvidia, laptop, hdmi, xrandr, tv

Sorry for my English. I am from Russia.

Laptop - Compaq presario cq61. Ubuntu 13.04
TV - Panasonic - VIERA TX-PR42C11

I need connect my laptop to TV via HDMI. When I had proprietary driver nVidia I could connect TV and it works as second monitor. But I couldn`t
change default resolution 1280x720. My TV works good with 1176x664. I tried to add necessary resolution using xrandr. But when I performed
"xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 1176x664_60.00" it says that it wouldn`t work because I used proprietary driver.

Then I have installed X.Org X Server driver.

Now I can add necessary resolution using xrandr. But when I connect TV it there isn`t any picture on it.

Please, answer my questions:

1) How can I add resolution 1176x664 if I use proprietary driver nVidia? OR

2) How make X.Org X Server work with TV?